# What is an Ordered Tree

Tags: tree

I am really sorry about asking this question, but I cannot find a satisfying answer. I have read a lot of sources about ordered trees, and they include such an explanation: An Ordered tree is a tree which children of each node are ordered by special rule. There is an instance for the ordered tree :

```
      7
    / | \
   3 10  4
  / \   / \
12   8 11  2
```

The third level makes sense because children of 3 and children of 4 are ordered in descending format.I think there is no any order between children of 7, but this tree is given as example of ordered tree.

Comment: Where is this example from?

Comment: It is from the book "Introduction to Algorithms".

Comment: It could be a partially ordered tree.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please share the page of Introduction of Algorithms where you read that? I can't find it.

There is a misconception between the order of the nodes of a tree and the order of the elements contained in the nodes.

A tree is ordered if for each children there is a child that is the first, another is the second and so on and so on. **That's it**. Without knowing what the elements of the node are, you know that which one is the first one, etc.

For a binary tree it will be: there is a node that is the left node and another that is the right node. Now, which one you want to be the left one and which one you want to be the right one that is a different discussion.

The problem is that in the examples the nodes are always numbers so you think that the order has to do with the values of the numbers. No, the number is just the element inserted on the node.

Now, supposed that I have this tree:

```
                Morris
             /    |     \
            /     |      \ 
         Smith Anderson Cooper
```

And I want to store this information and then I want to recreate it on the screen exactly that way. Will I be using an ordered tree? Yes, the nodes are ordered: the node for Smith goes first and the node for Anderson goes second in the list of children. This is the order property of the tree. What is the order among elements? None: it's arbitrary.

Now, for search trees, there is a second order relationship. The nodes will have a key that we usually derive from the element and we define where to insert the element based on the value of that key. The values of the key need to follow a total order relationship (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). This would be the rule of your definition, but that definition wouldn't work for the other example, because there's no rule, it's just arbitrary (unless arbitrariness can be considered a rule? the no-rule is a rule?).

Probably an easier way to express this is to say that a tree is ordered if for each node, its children are stored in a list. A list is an ordered data structure by definition. This is, one element is gonna be the first one, another the second one and so on. Even if you store numbers, those numbers might not be in order but the list itself has an order.